# Is it possible to compile Sprite Kit app/game for iOS 6?

Tags: ios6, game-engine, ios7, xcode5, sprite-kit

Is it possible to compile Sprite Kit (new feature with XCode5) app/game for iOS 6? 
I have compiled Application for deployment target iOS6, tested on simmulator but i dont know if it will work on physical device.

Comment: Someone with hi rep can add tag SpriteKit ;-)

Comment: Please check my answer below. If you need more details let me know.

Comment: Done, also updated the tag description.

Comment: I have just started learning Cocos 2D and Sprite Kit appeared - pufff!!! There is so many technologies you know. I would love to use the best one as there is no time to learn everything :>

Comment: @BlueConga If you are targeting iOS & Mac only it's probably better way to use SpriteKit. If you want to target Android also and you just starting out I think you should check Corona (although they started to be expensive).

Comment: @Idan I have heard about it. But it is based on LUA language? I dont have any experience with LUA.

Comment: @BlueConga Lua is script language which is very good for creating games. It is super simple!
To be honest, I'm using SpriteKit for my game but for other reasons...

Comment: @Idan - can you tell me this secret reason. :> I am lost now between SpriteKit, Cocos2D and this @#@#$ expensive Corona SDK

Comment: @BlueConga No secret. I just have too much iOS code and I want that to run on OS-X also easily. Corona is too simple for me and I don't like the IDE, Cocos2D is too complicate. So, I'm trying SpriteKit which support lots of features I want out of the box.

Comment: @idan with apportable you can also go to android now with Objective-C. check out http://www.apportable.com/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would say that this question violates the NDA, but this can be answered in a general way:  NO, you cannot.  Apple frameworks are *dynamically linked*.  What this means is that each version of iOS comes loaded with specific libraries from Apple, and they will be linked to at runtime instead of being compiled into your binary.  If you use a version of iOS that does not include these frameworks, your app will crash because it will be unable to find the library at runtime.

To be more accurate you can *compile* SpriteKit calls but you can't *run* SpriteKit calls.

Comment: Thanks... sprite Kit looks so nice... Just can hope that they will fix iOS 7 look and feel and it will get good coverage fast!

Comment: iOS 6 got to around 90% in about 9 months, from what I heard.  iOS adoption rates are very high.

Comment: it is ... but in current form iOS7 will not become so popular as iOS6 - there can be a bigger group of people who decide not to move to iOS7 at all.

Comment: You can compile and sure run it. You cannot use it though.
Same happens every time Apple adds new libraries/frameworks to the new SDK.

Comment: People may not like iOS 7 but that's normal when change happens. They *will* switch over as soon as more iOS 7-only apps become available and they feel left behind, that's when they'll bite the bullet. The rest probably aren't potential app customers anymore anyway, so no loss there.

Answer (score 3):

You can compile it but using that as "optional" (link with binary option just mark the library as "Optional" instead of "required") so that when you would use iOS 6 your app would still work and run on the device won't crash. You must pay attention that when calling to SpriteKit you would have to check that it is there...But that's another topic.

The problem is that On iOS 6 you would have to use another library/framework and not SpriteKit, Let say for example on iOS 6 you would use cocos2d with a very limited version of the game and when using more advanced OS that has SpriteKit you would give the user more features.

So it's possible but I'm not sure it is what you really want.